# Does a Great Old One Warlock have two-way telepathic communication with its thrall?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, telepathy

The warlock's Awakened Mind telepathy was [recently changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51575/is-the-warlocks-awakened-mind-telepathy-two-way-or-only-one-way) from "You can **communicate telepathically with**..." to "You can **speak telepathically to**..." with the intent of clarifying that the telepathy was one-way.

[Create Thrall's text](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#TheGreatOldOne), however,  also says "communicate telepathically", but it has not been changed:

> ... You can **communicate telepathically with** the charmed creature as long as the two of you are on the same plane of existence.

Also, the [Voice of the Chain Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#EldritchInvocations2) invocation says "communicate telepathically with", and I have never played with a DM who prevents a Chain warlock from two-way comms with its familiar:

> You can **communicate telepathically with** your familiar...

Does this imply that the warlock enjoys two-way telepathy with its thrall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You linked all the relevant material to answer this RAW. Awakened mind was indeed changed to one-way telepathy, while Create Thrall was not.

We can easily conclude that telepathy with a Thrall is two-way.

I might add that if the Awakened mind was nerfed to one-way only, Create Thrall only works on one creature at a time so there are fewer balance issues.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Antoine! Take the [tour] when you have a moment, or peruse the [help] for more details about the site.